# Why one circuit affects other circuits

Tags: electrical, circuit

When I use a power tool plugged into one of the 20 amp circuits, it affects two other circuits (the lights in my house in different locations on these two circuits flicker as I use the tool). The lights flicker as I increase and decrease the rpms on my power tool. Why is this happening? Please advise. Thank you. Ty

Comment: Could be a lot of things. The infamous weak, loose or non-existent neutral is one possibility.  Small service panel and small service wires with a long run to the transformer is another. What kind of lights? LED?   Some of the cheaper LED ones are HIGHLY sensitive to minor voltage variations. Also, what power tool are you using?

Comment: I second the possibility of a bad or weak neutral. If a high load make light brighter, that's a bad neutral.

Comment: "as I increase and decrease the rpms on my power tool"  So is the problem with only variable speed tools, or also with simpler constant speed devices? Do the lights flicker *only*  when increasing or decreasing the RPM?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you sure that this 20A circuit is independent of the flickering circuits?  It's not unheard of for someone to wire things in strange ways.

But even if they are different circuits, they still have a common HOT and NEUTRAL back at the panel.  If the power tool creates a heavy load on the circuit that can and often will be "seen" in all other circuits on that leg of the panel.

A couple of suggestions:

1. Be sure that your outlet, wiring, and circuit breaker connections are all firm and clean.  Loose or corroded connections cause voltage loss and that causes excess current to be drawn by induction or other motor-driven tools.
2. Check that your tool is in proper working condition.  If it's out of adjustment or needs maintenance, it may be drawing more power than usual.

Comment: it's not just induction motors, universal motors can do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a single neutral conductor is connected to multiple circuits, and the neutral conductor may not be sized appropriately to carry the load of the combined circuits.

For instance, if you have have multiple circuit breakers, each with their own 14ga hot wire going out to their individual circuit, but the same 14ga neutral wire connects all of those circuits back to the panel, then the neutral is a bottleneck, and voltage may drop as a result.

The other possibility is a limitation in the source feeding your panel. Undersized conductor, poor ground, loose connection, etc.

I would check the voltage at one of lights, and at the source of the panel (using appropriate precautions of course). Then check them again with the tool running, and look for any significant voltage sag.